# PHP ZWNG Character Send to TELEGRAM

Tags: php, api, encoding, telegram

Hello everyone i have question from encoding adn telegram

when i send a ZWNG Zero Width space from telegram desktop to my telegrambot like this:
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuVQ8.png)

it sends this : u200b
a json Like this :

```
 {"update_id":***,
"message":{"message_id":***,"***":{"id":***,"first_name":"***","last_name":"***","username":"***"},"chat":{"id":***,"first_name":"***","last_name":"***","username":"***","type":"***"},"date":***,"text":"u2068"}}
```

now i wanna send a message like this to my users With telegambot
question is here : how to send like this with robots?

i wanna send a ZWNG Zero Width space from telegrambot

Im using this code to send :

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.telegram.org/bot***/SendMessage");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "chat_id=230307754&parse_mode=Markdown&text=[".urldecode('200b')."](http://google.com)");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$json=curl_exec($curl);
$obj = json_decode($json);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to send some things like "می​شود" with your bot.
I recommend to you to use ZWSP (همون نیم فاصله).

You can copy it or use "Ctrl+Shift+2" or "Ctrl+- to insert ZWSP.

for example:

```
<?php
$chatId = "********";
$botToken = "*********:****************************";
$website = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$botToken;

sendMessage($chatId, "می​شود");exit;

function sendMessage ($chatId,$message) {
    $url = $GLOBALS[website]."/sendMessage?chat_id=".$chatId."&text=".urlencode($message);
    file_get_contents($url);
}

?>
```